# Bind Hibernate entity to table at runtime

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a database schema that contains multiple tables with different names, but all have the exact same column structure.  The database contains historical log data with one table per day.

I'd really like to be able to create a Hibernate mapping for the columns that I could reuse for each table.  Essentially I need a way to pass in a table name either when I create a session or when I execute a query.  I don't think Hibernate supports this, but I'd be interested to hear if anyone has an idea about how I could handle this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to implement a [Naming Strategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-namingstrategy)

Here's a [link](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=938354) to a discussion for a similar problem to yours

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in data read, you could use the [ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) to load the data from statement.