# How to change the Hibernate table name(@Table(name="tableName")) at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working in spring mvc with hibernate. I am new to this technology. I need to change the hibernate entity class table name at runtime?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tableName")
public class DynamicTable{

// column name with get set methods.
....
}
```

Here i need change the table name at runtime. My column is going to same only. Is it possible to change table name? If possible kindly explain me? if not tell me the alternate solution for this problem.

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378370/bind-hibernate-entity-to-table-at-runtime might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package net.petrikainulainen.hibernate.util;
import org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy;


public class CustomNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy {

    private static final String PLURAL_SUFFIX = "s";


    @Override
    public String classToTableName(String className) {
        String tableNameInSingularForm = super.classToTableName(className);
        return transformToPluralForm(tableNameInSingularForm);
    }

    private String transformToPluralForm(String tableNameInSingularForm) {
        StringBuilder pluralForm = new StringBuilder();

        pluralForm.append(tableNameInSingularForm);
        pluralForm.append(PLURAL_SUFFIX);

        return pluralForm.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. How to use this code in DAOImpl class. Could you please explain me?